# converting an service response object value to array with lodash

Tags: javascript, reactjs

not sure what is wrong with this

```
const info= getUserInfo('michael').then(response => {
      return _.map(response, value => {
        return value.Symbol
      })
    })
```

Service response is

```
//console.log(response)
    0:{UserId: "michael", Symbol: "ABC"}
    1:{UserId: "michael", Symbol: "ABD"}
    2:{UserId: "michael", Symbol: "XYZ"}
    3:{UserId: "michael", Symbol: "ZYX"}
    4:{UserId: "michael", Symbol: "CBA"}
```

in console.log I'm getting a promise response, which I don't understand why

```
//console.log(info)
Promise {_bitField: 0, _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined, _rejectionHandler0: undefined, _promise0: undefined, _receiver0: undefined, …}
```

The returned symbols are in `_rejectionHandler0`

My desire return is `['ABC', 'ABD', 'XYZ', 'ZYX', 'CBA']`

Comment: what does `getUserInfo` return?

Comment: because its a async call, and `getUserInfo` is returning a promise that you can see from console output, check the answer of duplicate ques, you will see all possible ways of fixing that issue :)

Comment: @MayankShukla he was already `.then`ing the return of that function, so I was just curious what the returned `Promise` looked like to see the `resolve` value

Comment: @Tony I get the same as //console.log(info) response, showing the promise info and the results inside the promise.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const info= getUserInfo('michael').then(response => {
    return _.map(response, value => {
        return value.Ticker
    })
})
```

you are accessing `Symbol` which is not on your response. it should be `Ticker`

Comment: Yea I noticed that typo mistake, I fixed the question but the problem still persists.